# How to update Label caption when EditBox text change using LiveBindings in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe5, livebindings

I can update the label caption when editbox text change if I use following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Caption:=Edit1.Text;
end;
```

If I do same with LiveBindings, It is only updating caption when I set focus on another control e.g. checkbox. I need to sync the label for each char I put in editbox. I used this

[image: this] 
setting to bind.

I also tried following code but did not work for me:
uses System.Bindings.helper;

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TBindings.Notify(Sender, 'Text');
end;
```

Please help. Many Thanks.

Comment: That´s just how bindings are designed for edit control (observers are notified from the control's `CM_EXIT` message handler).

Comment: Would you please let me know wiche bind able member from Edit and Label you use for this action?

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLinkObservers.ControlChanged(Sender as TEdit);
end;
```